# The value is not a Feature Layer. Failed to execute (AddRuleToTopology)?

Tags: arcpy, topology, error-000840

I am trying to create topology with ArcGIS python .
when I do the AddRuleToTopology its show the error as The value is not a Feature Layer. Failed to execute (AddRuleToTopology).
But I am tried Manually with AddRuleToTopology_management tool its working
but when copied snippet to python getting same error.
my code:

```
test10=arcpy.CreateTopology_management(r'D:\Velugoti\test.gdb\test','test10',0.01)
arcpy.AddFeatureClassToTopology_management(test10,r'D:\Velugoti\test.gdb\test\test',1,1)
arcpy.AddFeatureClassToTopology_management(test10,r'D:\Velugoti\test.gdb\test\test2',1,1)
arcpy.AddRuleToTopology_management(test10,"Must Not Self-Intersect (Line)",r'D:\Velugoti\test.gdb\test\test')
```

Its shows
 ERROR 000840: The value is not a Feature Layer. Failed to execute (AddRuleToTopology).

Comment: Use MakeFeatureLayer to create feature layers. Feature Classes added to the map are feature layers, that is probably why it works in ArcMap

Answer (score 1):

The third parameter of `AddRuleToTopology`must be a feature layer, not a feature class. Add a `MakeFeatureLayer` command to your code, similar to this:

```
test10=arcpy.CreateTopology_management(r'D:\Velugoti\test.gdb\test','test10',0.01)
arcpy.AddFeatureClassToTopology_management(test10,r'D:\Velugoti\test.gdb\test\test',1,1)
arcpy.AddFeatureClassToTopology_management(test10,r'D:\Velugoti\test.gdb\test\test2',1,1)
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(r'D:\Velugoti\test.gdb\test\test', 'test_layer')
arcpy.AddRuleToTopology_management(test10,"Must Not Self-Intersect (Line)", 'test_layer')
```

Comment: Its not working .Still get same error.